# stack ghci stop showing which files are loaded

Tags: haskell-stack

I have a Haskell project which is quite huge. And I load this project using stack ghci in commandline.
This works great, but now if try to do some simple arithmethic, it looks like this:

```
*[All loaded files in alphabetical order]*> 1+2
3
*[All loaded files in alphabetical order]*>
```

Where *[All loaded files in alphabetical order]* is taking up huge parts of the screen. Is there a way to stop ghci from showing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:set prompt "λ "
```

Or, if you'd rather not use unicode,

```
:set prompt "> "
```

You can also put this in a `~/.ghci` file so that you don't need to retype it on every load.

Might consider making this a default for `stack ghci`, hmm..